# In Safari, both "NEW TAB" and "NEW TAB AT END" always do *exactly* the same thing: add tab at end. Fix?

Tags: keyboard, safari, shortcut, menu-bar

Hi all– So when I click on "New Tab" OR "New Tab At End" (pressing the Option key) from the File menu (same if I use only the associated hotkeys), the same thing happens: I get a new tab at the *end* of all the tabs I have open in that particular Safari window. Am I missing something? Isn't New Tab supposed to open a new tab immediately to the right of the tab you're currently in?

Thanks in advance for any insight into this--

Comment: I forgot to mention: I'm running Monterey on a MacBook Pro 13" from 2017. This glitch I described is the only one I've noticed in using Safari.

Comment: On Big Sur Macbook Pro 15" 2016 and adding tabs either way works fine.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas / suggestions? I still can't get this to work. Help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I'm still hoping someone can enlighten me regarding this issue:when I click on "New Tab" OR "New Tab At End" (pressing the Option key) from the File menu (same if I use only the associated hotkeys), the same thing happens: I get a new tab at the end of all the tabs I have open in that particular Safari window. Am I missing something? Isn't New Tab supposed to open a new tab immediately to the right of the tab you're currently in?
Anyone able to help?